# Replace values of outliers with mean of closest normal data points in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am to perform seasonal decomposition on around 1000 time series which can contain outliers. I want to replace the outliers with a mean value, since the outlier can corrupt the seasonality extraction.

```
 df  

 TimeStamp   |   value
 2021-01-01       1
 2021-01-02       5
 2021-01-03       23
 2021-01-04       18
 2021-01-05       7
 2021-01-06       3 
    ...
```

Outliers are defined as any sample with an absolute z-score larger than 3.

```
df['zscore'] = scipy.stats.zscore(df['value'])
```

I can identify the timestamp of all outliers

```
(df['zscore'].abs() >= 3]).index
```

which in above example would return

```
[2021-01-03,2021-01-04]
```

Given this list of indexes, how do I replace the value with the mean of the closest previous and next neighbors such that I get the following output?

```
 df_mod

 TimeStamp   |   value
 2021-01-01       1
 2021-01-02       5
 2021-01-03       6
 2021-01-04       6
 2021-01-05       7
 2021-01-06       3 
    ...
```

Would appreciate any help on how to realize this type of function / logic.

**EDIT**

There can exists NaN values in the time series from the beginning, which I do not want to replace with mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `value` to `NaN` by condition in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then for replace by mean sum forward and back filling values with divide by `2`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
orig = df.index
df = df.dropna(subset=['value'])
df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df['zscore'].abs() >= 3)
df['value'] = df['value'].ffill().add(df['value'].bfill()).div(2)
df = df.reindex(orig)
```

Solution without helper column:

```
zscore = scipy.stats.zscore(df['value'])

df['value'] = df['value'].mask(zscore.abs() >= 3)
df['value'] = df['value'].ffill().add(df['value'].bfill()).div(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I tried this I also noticed that some time series had NaN values already from the start, which I don't want to do bfill or ffill with, is it possible to mask with some other value than NaN and do this, such that only specifically the zscore >=3 gets filled?

Comment: @kspr - Can you check edit? Do you need first remove NaNs, apply solution and last add them?